# Linking errors on compilation of simple OpenCV testing code (two OpenCV versions installed side by side)

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I want to have OpenCV in two versions - 4 and 3 (I want to practice a bit with C API, which was removed in version 4, if I understand correctly). I have Kubuntu 20.04. I compiled and installed both OpenCV versions in custom directories .../opencv/install3 and .../opencv/install4. Compilation did not throw any errors. I used the following options for configuring cmake (only installation paths were different):

```
cmake -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D ENABLE_AVX=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_TBB=ON -D WITH_EIGEN=OFF -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D WITH_VTK=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<mypath>/opencv/install4 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<mypath>/opencv_contrib/modules <mypath>/opencv/
```

However, compilation of a testing file "cppopencv.cpp" fails with messages:

```
g++ -I<mypath>/opencv/install4/include/opencv4 -c cppopencv.cpp -o cppopencv.o -std=c++11
g++  cppopencv.o -L<mypath>/opencv/install4/lib/ -lopencv_highgui  -o cppopencv 
/usr/bin/ld: cppopencv.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi'
/usr/bin/ld: <mypath>/opencv/install4/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:3: cppopencv] Error 1
```

Testing code and cmake options for OpenCV compilation taken from here: http://techawarey.com/programming/install-opencv-c-c-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-step-by-step-guide/
Testing code includes only "highgui" library:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
 
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  
  cv::Mat image;
  image = cv::imread("opencv_testimage.png" ,cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
  
  if(! image.data ) {
      std::cout <<  "Image not found or unable to open" << std::endl ;
      return -1;
    }
  
  cv::namedWindow( "Techawarey:OpenCV Test Program", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::imshow( "Techawarey:OpenCV Test Program", image );
  
  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Please help me to identify what is wrong.

Comment: link also to the missing library `-lopencv_imgcodecs`, and also at least `-lopencv_core`

Comment: Thank you @Miki, that worked with both versions!

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked well for both versions 3 and 4 with additional libraries linked (thanks @[Miki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008845/miki) for the correct answer):

```
g++ -I<mypath>/opencv/install4/include/opencv4 -c cppopencv.cpp -o cppopencv.o -std=c++11
g++ cppopencv.o -L<mypath>/opencv/install4/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -o cppopencv
```